# Memory Management of imported C++ methods in C#

Tags: c#, c++, user32, intptr

I have a Windows Forms Application that imports and uses some C++ methods from user32.dll.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(int xPoirnt, int yPoint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandel, IntPtr childAfter, String sClassName, String windowTitle);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    private static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, long count);
```

I've noticed that after my app runs for an extended period of time, the memory usage can go up to 500~MB (initial 5MB).

I don't have that much C++ experience but I know that you have to manually do memory management for C++.

My questions is, do I have to do memory management for my app or will the C# garbage collector handle it.

Comment: "but I know that you have to manually do memory management for C++" - in the "bad old days" you more or less did need to. But these days we have smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` & `std::weak_ptr`) as well as capable container classes, so manual memory management (and associated leaks) are largely a thing of the past (but only if you take advantage and *use* those facilities in C++11/14/17 of course - but you *really* should).

Comment: From memory, most of those functions don't need any memory management; the glaring counter-example is PrintWindow (it uses a DC!).  However, your best bet is to look on the http://pinvoke.net wiki and go through the examples for each function.  Also, with any Windows Forms app, you need to worry about disposing all of the bits and pieces in your application.  One other thing you can do is put in a call to GC.Collect in debug builds of your app (after some event).  Only compare freshly GC-ed memory footprints.  .NET apps have a natural saw-tooth memory profile over time.